# Passing a HTML parameter through AJAX to C# MVC Controller Action

Tags: c#, html, ajax

I am trying to pass a HTML string as a parameter through the following means:

```
$.ajax({
    url: sourceUrl,
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
etc...
}
```

where sourceURL is a call to a C# Controller action with a parameter that contains a HTML string (from a Rich Text Box). Something like:

```
var sourceURL = "ThisController/ThisAction?Parameter=" + varWithHTML;
```

However it fails stating:

> A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client `(description="<p>Rich Text String</p>")`.

I have tried wrapping the string in a encodeURI():

```
encodeURIComponent(varWithHTML)
```

but still the same problem. I have also another suggestion for this issue in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

And still no luck.
Am I going mad or is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Why are you passing something with a GET request?  This is why POST exists

Comment: does this ajax call send `data` argument?

Comment: Good point maccettura - I had quickly copied and posted some code and that snook through. derloopkat - I have placed a breakpoint on the controller action and that is not even being hit. When I check Event Viewer I get the above error message.

Comment: @CJH well if you change this to a POST and pass that HTML in the body of your POST request I imagine you wont be needing our help anymore.

Comment: I'm asking about the ajax call, not the success function.

Comment: Oh sorry... So, there is no data argument being sent... Should that make a difference? (You might guess this is quite new to me)

Comment: maccesttura... Thanks for the advice... I have change to a post but still getting the same problem. When you say "pass the HTML in the body of the POST request" are you able to elaborate on that please? I have not done much work here and would appreciate any help!

Comment: ... Ahhh you mean through the data...(as per derloopkat)?! Yes!

Comment: Do you NEED the html tags on the parameter string?  Are they always 'p' tags?  You probably don't need them if they are always the same.  The error you're receiving is specifically regarding html tags in the text.  There are ways to disable this validation, as shown in the answer.  The better way would be not passing html formatted text, and just pass the text.  Check how you are getting that text from your form element, you can probably access a similar attribute that is not HTML formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use POST method and pass the html body as Post Body, also you need to turn off `ValidateInput`, you simply need to put this line above your action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]//This line is to let you pass html in parameters.
public ActionResult ThisAction()
```

But be **careful**! That may put your site on risk of being **Cross Site Scripting Attack (XSS)** which may let a Hacker can easily edit the request when it pass on and put a javascript within it. You may need to handle that manually, as `ValidateInput` was made for that reason.

To avoid that you need to pass the input through Html Encoding and replace each brackets for every tag you want to be allowed only, for example:

You want to enable tag `<b> </b>` only, then you need to replace `&lt;b&gt;` to `<b>` and `&lt;/b&gt;` to `</b>` before you save them in data or whatever you want to do with them!

```
[ValidateInput(false)]//This line is to let you pass html in parameters.
public ActionResult ThisAction(string htmlString)
{
    StringBuilder sbHtmlString = new StringBuilder();

    // Encode the htmlString.
    sbHtmlString.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(htmlString));

    // Only decode bold tag and ignore anything else!
    sbHtmlString.Replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>");
    sbHtmlString.Replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>");
    htmlString = sbHtmlString.ToString();

    //Do whatever you want with htmlString 

    return View();
}
```

Good Luck.